# AWS S3 and Cloudfront: Limit access to s3-object to a specific user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to limit the access of S3-objects to a specific user. My structure is defined as follows:

- Objects are prepared in the backend and URLs to this object is created via Cloudfront-Signers (using my aws-account public/private-key)
- URLs are returned to the users
- User tries to access the file via URL
- I am running a cloudfront viewer-function to validate the access

The question now is: How do I validate access to this file? By default, there is no way to retrieve informatio about who is accessing the file when calling the viewer-request.
What I found most effecting is to also pass the user-id in the url this way:

- old: https://files.mydomain.com/path/to/my/object
- new: https://files.mydomain.com/user/path/to/my/object

This way I get the user and am able to validate the access. `path/to/my/object` got a project-id in it‘s header, with that I can check if the user is allowed to access the file.

I know this isn't exactly safe. I played around with encrypting the user in the url - but this leads to completely unique urls for every access cause the browser-cache to fail.

Also in the viewer-request, I have to make multiple requests which is rather slow. I have to:

- Fetch the objects head
- Fetch the objects project and roles (via aws dynamodb)

This can take up to 800-1600ms, for each request. I am caching those values inside my viewer-request lambda, which helps a lot. But meh,...

Is there an other way to achieve something like this? It‘s important that every file has a reference to a project and by this it can be validated.

Comment: Are these a) application-level users b) Cognito users or c) IAM users?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Cognito users

Comment: If you don't need instantaneous access, have you thought of using IAM policies to control which Cognito users have access?